# How to use JS functions in included views in Laravel with blade?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, include, laravel-blade

I want to use some javascript functions in included file (**properties.blade.php**) in Laravel blade views.

**View (*index.blade.php*)**

```
@extends('layouts.master') 

@section('filters')
    @include('partials.filters.properties')
@endsection

@section('content')
<!-- properties start -->
<div class="container">
...
</div>
<!-- properties end -->
@endsection

@section('javascript')
<!-- This is the JS file, I want to include in header as well (functions.js) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('/js/functions.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

**Filter (*properties.blade.php*)**

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('properties.search') }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 ui-widget component"  id="f_loc">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="input-tags" type="search" name="q" class="form-control input-text input-lg" placeholder="City, Community or Tower">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="search-button" onclick="searchSubmit()">Search &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS (*functions.js*)**

```
function searchSubmit() {
    localStorage.setItem("search", $('#input-tags').val());
}
```

I am getting this error in console:
[image: error]

Comment: Are you sure about the js path? Maybe you missed the 'assets' in front? Look at your console. Where does it search to find the functions.js? You should get a 404.

Comment: are you rendering the `javascript` section anywhere?

Comment: no it is correct as rest of the JS code is working from index.blade.php @TaniaPetsouka

Comment: @apokryfos yes I've rendered it as functions.js (View section, 2nd-last line)

Comment: Ideally you should just add an event listener inside the functions.js file where you know the function is defined. There's a good chance it is not yet defined when the browser is parsing the line where it is first referenced.

Comment: do you have a @yield javascript on your layouts.master?

Comment: @TaniaPetsouka exactly

Comment: @apokryfos can you ellaborate how or give some reference plz?

Comment: In `function.js` add line `$("button.search-button").on("click", searchSubmit);` and remove the `onclick="searchSubmit()"` part from the button.

Comment: thanks but I've used it in this way... Can't it be used the other way (onclick)???

Comment: put your **js** in public folder and  instead of ```{{ url('/js/functions.js')}}``` access it using ```{{public_path('js/functions.js')}}```

Comment: accessing the file is not my issue... its already working (accessing other methods and event listeners) but the issue is to access it in included file `partials/filters/properties.blade.php` provided that it is already included in parent file `properties/index.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use blade's `@push` directive for JavaScript and css so you can add it to an `@stack('js')`, for example. The stack would be just before your closing body tag.

The `@section` runs the risk of getting replaced if it comes across another one.

Also as a side note, you are ending the last section with `@stop`..